# Javascript error when using theme runtime portlet liferay

Tags: javascript, themes, liferay, portlet, velocity

I try to include my customizing Navigation portlet to first column of my themes
So I had tried to use following code in my layout template: (\ROOT\layouttpl\custom\3_columns.tpl)

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false")
$theme.runtime("71_INSTANCE_MAIN", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

It work fine, expect, When enter Manage->Page, and select one pages in pages tree (diffrent of current page) then select Layout on configuration panel
it return javascript error and stop working

```
Timestamp: 06/09/2012 7:08:59 PM
Error: TypeError: j._container is null
Source File: http://localhost:8080/combo/?browserId=firefox&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=6100&t=1345609853640&p=/html/js&m=/aui/aui-state-interaction/aui-state-interaction-min.js&m=/aui/widget-child/widget-child-min.js&m=/aui/aui-button-item/aui-button-item-min.js&m=/aui/aui-char-counter/aui-char-counter-min.js&m=/aui/aui-data-set/aui-data-set-min.js&m=/aui/widget-parent/widget-parent-min.js&m=/aui/aui-toolbar/aui-toolbar-min.js&m=/aui/aui-panel/aui-panel-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&m=/aui/dd-constrain/dd-constrain-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&m=/aui/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize/aui-resize-base-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize/aui-resize-constrain-min.js&m=/aui/aui-dialog/aui-dialog-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize-iframe/aui-resize-iframe-min.js&m=/aui/aui-dialog-iframe/aui-dialog-iframe-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-data-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-node-min.js&m=/aui/dd-proxy/dd-proxy-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-view-min.js&m=/aui/dataschema-base/dataschema-base-min.js&m=/aui/dataschema-xml/dataschema-xml-min.js&m=/aui/sortable/sortable-min.js&m=/liferay/undo_manager.js&m=/liferay/auto_fields.js&m=/liferay/form_navigator.js&m=/aui/querystring-parse-simple/querystring-parse-simple-min.js&m=/aui/history-base/history-base-min.js&m=/aui/history-html5/history-html5-min.js&m=/liferay/history.js&m=/liferay/history_html5.js&m=/liferay/history_manager.js&m=/liferay/panel.js&m=/aui/aui-paginator/aui-paginator-min.js&m=/liferay/panel_floating.js&m=/liferay/search_container.js
Line: 1

Timestamp: 06/09/2012 7:08:59 PM
Error: TypeError: l is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:8080/combo/?browserId=firefox&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=6100&t=1345609853640&p=/html/js&m=/aui/aui-state-interaction/aui-state-interaction-min.js&m=/aui/widget-child/widget-child-min.js&m=/aui/aui-button-item/aui-button-item-min.js&m=/aui/aui-char-counter/aui-char-counter-min.js&m=/aui/aui-data-set/aui-data-set-min.js&m=/aui/widget-parent/widget-parent-min.js&m=/aui/aui-toolbar/aui-toolbar-min.js&m=/aui/aui-panel/aui-panel-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&m=/aui/dd-constrain/dd-constrain-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&m=/aui/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&m=/aui/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&m=/aui/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize/aui-resize-base-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize/aui-resize-constrain-min.js&m=/aui/aui-dialog/aui-dialog-min.js&m=/aui/aui-resize-iframe/aui-resize-iframe-min.js&m=/aui/aui-dialog-iframe/aui-dialog-iframe-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-data-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-node-min.js&m=/aui/dd-proxy/dd-proxy-min.js&m=/aui/aui-tree/aui-tree-view-min.js&m=/aui/dataschema-base/dataschema-base-min.js&m=/aui/dataschema-xml/dataschema-xml-min.js&m=/aui/sortable/sortable-min.js&m=/liferay/undo_manager.js&m=/liferay/auto_fields.js&m=/liferay/form_navigator.js&m=/aui/querystring-parse-simple/querystring-parse-simple-min.js&m=/aui/history-base/history-base-min.js&m=/aui/history-html5/history-html5-min.js&m=/liferay/history.js&m=/liferay/history_html5.js&m=/liferay/history_manager.js&m=/liferay/panel.js&m=/aui/aui-paginator/aui-paginator-min.js&m=/liferay/panel_floating.js&m=/liferay/search_container.js
Line: 1
```

I had tried with some another portlet(such as webcontent display(56)), but it still return me the same javascript error.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the code you have added in

\ROOT\layouttpl\custom\3_columns.tpl

Because whenever you select Manage-> Page, max.tpl will get applied which is there in

\ROOT\layouttpl\standard/max.tpl.

So the problem is something else.

Comment: I dont think so, if i have removed that runtime code it would work without any javascript error !

Comment: in documentation that I found, this code should be something like $proccessor.proccessPortlet("portletId"), but with it, I can not pre-define any preferences for the portlet, however, it can work with javascript error